# How do I insert data from JSP to MySQL database?

Tags: java, html, mysql, database, jsp

I have already made the jsp file (which receives data from the html form) and the database (using MySQL workbench).

contact.jsp code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"  errorPage="errorpage.jsp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Messages from contact us page</h3>
      <ul>
         <li><p><b>Name:</b>
            <%= request.getParameter("name")%>
         </p></li>
         <li><p><b>Email:</b>
            <%= request.getParameter("txtEmail")%>
         </p></li>
         <li><p><b>Message:</b>
            <%= request.getParameter("txtMessage")%>
         </p></li>
      </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Database name: KSG_Database
Schema: web_data
Table: contact_messages
Columns: c_name , email , txtmessage

Now I just need the code to insert the input data from the form to the database.  Can someone please help me?

Comment: Do not put Java in JSP.  Post the html to a servlet and insert into the DB from there. **MVC**

Comment: @BLAZE MASON If you have established a connection from your JSP Code to your Mysql database using Mysql's JDBC Driver?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call, from the JSP and through a form, an "action". That "action" will process the data it gets from the jsp and do whatever it needs to do (the connection with the database), and finally return to the servlet the nextPage.

The form in the jsp should look like this:

```
<form action="<%= response.encodeURL("/path/nameOfController?action=accions.nameAction") %>" method="POST"> 
// whatever data you want to send to db in inputs like this:
<input type="HIDDEN" name="name" value=<%=variableName%>>
</form>
```

What's inside action is the path of the "action" you want to call. You will process that in the controller, and use that "nameAction" to call the action as you prefere (here I use a Factory to call the classes). Here's how I manage  it:

In the doGet of the controller:

```
Action action=null;
String nextPage=null;
String nameAction = request.getParameter("action");
// get the action acording to what was sent through the jsp form
action= FactoryImpl.getReference().getAction(nameAction);
// run the action with whatever method, in this case it's called execute
nextPage = action.execute(request, response);
// nextPage has returned the name of the next jsp, now just sent the redirect
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(response.encodeURL(nextPage));
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Now, you just have to create the "action", and inside the execute method, connect to the db and make the inserts you need to. Also, I would recommend to make the connection in another class and get it from the action, just so you don't have it all in the same class.

The Action class should something like this:

```
package whatever;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import presentacio.Action;

public class nameOfTheAction implements Action {

    public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        //connection with db
        return "nameOfNextJspToSendToClient";
    }

}
```

Now, just if you're wondering, I use an interface which is Action, and all the actions implement that interface. If you want to know how the interface looks like, here it is, but you don't need to do it like me:

```
package presentacio;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public interface Action{
    public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception;

}
```

If I haven't explained myself well enough, or you want me to detail something, just ask.

Answer (score 1):

### First, Import the JDBC Driver:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
```

else

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
```

### Then Second, Value your Strings:

```
    String your_name       = request.getParameter("name");
    String your_Email      = request.getParameter("txtEmail");
    String your_txtMessage = request.getParameter("txtMessage");
```

### Then, create a connection to your database:

```
try{

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");// Driver to establish connection to the database
    Connection con1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/KSG_Database","your_id","your_pass"); //Create connection using your ID and Password
    Statement st1=con1.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs1=st1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM contact_messages");
    while(rs1.next()){

    //-----------------------------Then, Create an InsertQuery using a String:---------------------

    String InsertQuery = "insert into contact_messages (c_name,email,txtmessage) values('"+your_name+"','"+your_Email+"','','"+your_txtMessage+"');";

    //-----------------------------Finally, Execute your Insert Query:-----------------------------

    st1.executeUpdate(InsertQuery);}}

catch(Exception error){
    out.println(error);}
```

**It worked for me.
If you have doubts ask me! :-)**